# Group Azure Table Storage Tables

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have a current task that would require the creation of Azure TableStorage Tables on the fly (C#), and inserting entities. That part is ok now.

There now is a requirement to *group* these tables into some form of commonality to form something that would resemble a tree structure.

Say:

Storage Account has Several Groups and each group has several tables.

Was considering using something in the lines of how one would just add names to Blob Storage to have something that looks like a path, but naming tables with _ or / is not an option.

I hope I was able to state the situation clear. Please do not hesitate to reply for both answers, or clarifications.

Comment: saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611574/create-directory-hierarchy-structure-in-azure-tables-storage but am afraid it will leave me with just one table :(

Comment: It would help if you could provide some context as to why this is needed.

Comment: Hello Herve,

The application shall be used by multiple users. Each user can create multiple accounts. Each account has activity that is logged. 

The accounts are not the same across the board, they will have different and multiple log data. 

So for this, and maybe a sensible data retrieval process, I would like to retrieve data as User1/Account1/Account1Process1Log; which can also be User1/Account1/Account1Process2Log

I hope I was able to express clearly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. You could name your tables along those lines:  user1-account1-accountprocess1log. Or name the table user1, and have a PartitionKey with 'account1', and a GUID for the RowKey to make it unique; then store the process name in another field. The best way to find the solution to your naming convention is to first start by your read objectives: what do you need to access quickly and/or often?

Comment: Hello Herve. Thank you for that suggestion. Am also looking into it, but wouldn't that result in me having only one table? 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Eduardo. No, you would have one table per user/account/processlog in the first scenario. Or one table per user in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
- namespacing your tables (using the authorized chars, it wont look very good because of the "only alphanumerical" rule)
- use the rest API to create storage accounts (the only table grouping azure provides)
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh264518.aspx)